# React.FC setState in child component doesn't update the view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

So what I am doing right now is creating a form that sends a request to backend and gets back with dispatching an action and setting a state.

Basically it's company information, and I have to use it across the form, which can be filled with data from backend but there's this one thing;

I have parent element in which I am passing [state,setState] as prop, in child I am using setState and it's all working fine and dandy as I check it in ReduxDevTool. 
The problem is that when I access the same state in next step I am unable to recieve any data because the useState is an object with empty keys, and that's not very useful in futher form steps.

I've tried reaching out to documentation and check if I should be using some fucnctions like `getDerivedStateFromProps` but in React.FC with typescript things are not as easy as that, or it's my lack of experience in that matter.

*Some pseudo code:*

```
App(){
  [state,setState] = useState({name:'', regon:'', phone:''})
  return(
    <div>
      <SomeComponent state={state} stateSetter={setState} />
      <SomeOtherComponent useGlobalState={state}/>
    </div>
  )
}
SomeComponent ({state, stateSetter}){
  <input 
    onChange={e=>{
      stateSetter((previousState)=>({...previousState, numberOne:{
        ...previousState.numberOne: e.target.value
      }}))}
    }
  >
}
SomeOtherComponent ({useGlobalState}){
  return <div>{useGlobalState.numberOne}</div>
}
```

I would want my form to use new state derived from backend, but all it remembers is last dispatched action output (which is not newest one, but rather a one step behind in terms of state).

Comment: (IMHO) this is a terrible use case for functional components. use a regular component, await the result of the data and then pass it as a prop to the component. it may seem like rocket science but it isn't.

Comment: @r3wt Honestly, I don't know at this point what your idea of perfect FC is, but I am pretty sure I should be able to use state.
Disclaimer: my FC is not only doing that, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

here is fixed code.

```
App(){
  const [state,setState] = useState({name:'', regon:'', phone:''}) //add const
  return(
    <div>
      <SomeComponent state={state} stateSetter={setState} />
      <SomeOtherComponent useGlobalState={state}/>
    </div>
  )
}
SomeComponent ({state, stateSetter}){
  <input 
    name="name"
    onChange={e=>{
      stateSetter({...state, numberOne:{...state.numberOne, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}}) // set object key, and put the variable to the stateSetter's argument, not function.
    }
  >
}
SomeOtherComponent ({useGlobalState}){
  return <div>{useGlobalState.numberOne}</div>
}
```

and Here is an example

```js
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    return(
        <input style={{border: '1px solid red', width: '100%'}} onChange={handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
class Component2 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { value } = this.props;
    return(
        <div style={{border: '1px solid red', width: '100%', height: 30}} >{value}</div>
    );
  }
}
class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  };
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  
  render(){
    const { value } = this.state;
    return(
      <div style={{border: '1px solid red', height: 100}}>
        <Component1 handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <Component2 value={value}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey! It's not that in my code I forgot the const. It's more than that.

Comment: and see the onChange attribute of the input.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why should that do the trick? It doesn't seem to be tackling my issue with state not re-rendering my FC. Thanks!